como extraer datos de un cvs y ingresarlos a una vista?
Hola soy nueva programando tengo un codigo en .js y necesito extraer datos de un archivo cvs y despues pasar esos datos a una tabla de una vista en html, ya me extrae los datos que necesito pero los imprime en consola ahora lo que necesito es que me los pase a mi tabla de mi vista este es mi codigo que ya realiza la extración de datos que requiero
```rows.forEach(row => {
                  if(row.length > 0){
                    console.log('tipo de registro: '+row.substring(0,2))//tipo de registro
                    console.log('numero de secuencia: '+row.substring(2,9))//numero de secuencia
                     

         

y mi código donde intento pasar los datos del código de arriba es este y es el que necesito encontrar la solución ya que solo me imprime esos datos pero no los del código de arriba
 rows.forEach(row => {
                  const rows = [

                      { data: 'tipo de registro'},
                      { data: 'numero de secuencia' },
                      
                     
                  ]
                  const tableBody = document.getElementById('tblDevolucion').querySelector('tbody');

                  rows.forEach(row => {
                      const newRow = document.createElement('td');
                      for (const key in row) {
                          if (row.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                              const cell = document.createElement('td');
                              cell.textContent = row[key];
                              newRow.appendChild(cell);
                          }
                      }
                      tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
                  });


                 })





              `


Tu código es confuso, lo único que entiendo es que:

Ya tienes solucionado el tema de cargar y leer el CSV
Tienes que cargarlo en el body de una tabla, es decir el CSV viene sin cabeceras.

Dado el primer punto te daré un ejemplo a partir de un string, es decir como si el CSV ya estuviera cargado dentro de una variable.
Los CSV tienen siempre un separador de columnas, que puede ser una coma, un punto y coma, un tab (\t) u otros. Y paras las filas se separa con un salto de línea (\n).
Lo que tienes que hacer, es ir separando (split) por filas y celdas, y luego volver a unir (join) pero ahora con formato HTML, es decir usando <td> y <tr>
Ejemplo:


const separador = ";";
const CSV = `A1;A2;A3
B1;B2;B3
C1;C2;C3`;


const tableBody = document.getElementById('tblDevolucion').querySelector('tbody');

tableBody.innerHTML = CSV.split("\n")
                        .map(f=> "<tr>" + 
                                    f.split(separador)
                                     .map(c=> "<td>" + c + "</td>")
                                     .join("") +
                                 "</tr>")
                        .join("");
                                 
<table id="tblDevolucion">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>



